# Looking for a specific converse lyapunov theorem: Given a asymptotically stable set there exists a Lyapunov function.

Tags: reference-request, dynamical-systems, lyapunov-functions

> **Problem**
>
> I am looking for a reference for a converse Lyapunov function theorem that proves, given an asymptotically stable set there exists a Lyapunov function for it.

I have seen a lot of proofs that given a given an asymptotically stable fixed point there exists a Lyapunov function for it. I am looking for something similar but for some asymptotically stable subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. I am not assuming that the set is well behaved(i.e. the interior of the set may be chaotic). The definition of asymptotically stable I am using is the following: The system
$$\dot{x}=f(x),x(0)=x_0$$
has an asymptotically stable fixed point $\bar{x}$, if for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that,if $||x(0)-\bar{x}||<\delta$ the for every $t\geq 0$ we have $||x(0)-\bar{x}|| <\epsilon$ and  $\lim_{t\to\infty}||x(0)-\bar{x}||=0$. For an asymptotically stable set my definition is similar except that $x^*\in D$ and the point closest(by the euclidean metric) to $x(t)$. $D$ is a compact a asymptotically stable set. If $x(t)\in D$ then $x^*=x(t)$.

**Notes**

- If any clarification is needed tell me and I will update my question.
- If there is some way I can reinterpret other converse Lyapunov theorem  functions into the type described in my problem please let me know.

Comment: Suggestion:  provide a definition of ***asymptotically stable set***!  Cheers!

Comment: There is [Conley's theorem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/129454/conley-theorem-or-fundamental-theorem-of-dynamical-systems) which is relevant to your question.

Comment: @RobertLewis Thank you for the comment. There are different definitions, so it is import to be clear.

Comment: @Evgeny Norton's paper on the theorem has been on my ever growing stack of papers to read. Unfortunately my knowledge on chain reoccurrence and complete Lyapunov functions is limited so I have been reading more introductory material.

Comment: @AzJ Looks like this is the most general result on this topic, so it's worth understanding key ideas at least. I'm also interested in Conley's papers, but haven't managed to read them carefully yet.